# Python Flask, MongoDB returning NULL

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, flask

I am re-purposing some code I got from the web. It is using Python Flask, MongoDb and javascript to display some data in a graph. I have only one document in MongoDB. When I go to http://localhost:5000/dq/projectdq I can see the following in the browser:

> [{"Month": "11/30/2015", "Actual": "14%", "KDEs with no issues": 23,
>   "KDEs with issues": 7}]

But when I go to http://localhost:5000 I see nothing and based on some debugging it seems there is no data coming to index.html. Here is the alert message:

> localhost:5000 says null

**Here is my dq.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps
from flask import jsonify # <- `jsonify` instead of `json`

app = Flask(__name__)

MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
DBS_NAME = 'dq'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'projects'
FIELDS = {'Month': True, 'Actual': True, 'KDEs with no issues': True, 'KDEs with issues': True, '_id': False}


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/dq/projectdq')
def donorschoose_projects():
    connection = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
    collection = connection[DBS_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
    projects = collection.find(projection=FIELDS, limit=1)
    #projects = collection.find(projection=FIELDS)
    json_projects = []
    for project in projects:
        json_projects.append(project)
        json_projects = json.dumps(json_projects, default=json_util.default)
        connection.close()
        return json_projects
    #return json_projects

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

**Below is the javascript that is trying to use the data from above dq.py:**

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/dq/projectdq")
    .await(makeGraphs);


function makeGraphs(error, projectsJson) {
    alert(error);
    var donorschooseProjects = projectsJson;

    var ndx = crossfilter(donorschooseProjects);

    var monthDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["Month"]; });

    var actualByMonth = monthDim.group(); 

    var all = ndx.groupAll();

    var lineChart = dc.lineChart("#line-chart");

    lineChart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,20]))
    .interpolate('step-before')
    .renderArea(true)
    .brushOn(false)
    .clipPadding(10)
    .yAxisLabel("This is the Y Axis!")
    .dimension(monthDim)
    .group(actualByMonth);

    dc.renderAll();

};
```

Comment: What do you mean "I see nothing"? Empty page ? No data ? What does `curl http://localhost:5000` returns (assuming you're using linux)? Is there an index.html file in your template directory?